# Symsquare Number 04

Tags: word, cryptic-clues

Symsquare6: The answer is a square grid which has the same words vertically and horizontally. The clue is a single sentence written in cryptic style and includes one anagram, one hidden word, one Charade, one straight clue and one Double Meaning, all as syntactically separate units. One of the words has NOT been clued:

> Vicar usually meets an asian from the east to surround the group and generate result.

HINT

> (Vicar usually) (meets an asian from the east)(to surround the group) and (generate) (result).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the solution is supposed to look like this:

> ```
>  C I R C L E
>  I C A R U S
>  R A * E S T
>  C R E A T E
>  L U S T R E
>  E S T E E M
> ```

With the clue parts defined as follows:

**Anagram**

> *"result"* - anagrams to LUSTRE.

**Hidden word**

> *"Vicar usually"* - hides ICARUS.

**Charade**

> *"meets an asian from the east"* - gives us MEETS + E (where 'asian' suggests 'eastern'), which is then all reversed ('from the east') to give ESTEEM.

**Straight clue**

> *"generate"* = CREATE.

**Double Meaning**

> *"to surround the group"* = CIRCLE, which means both 'to surround' and a 'group' (e.g. my 'circle of friends', or the 'inner circle' of an organisation).

**Unclued word**

> This leaves us with a word of the pattern RA_EST, which could be either RAREST or RAWEST.

Comment: I missed a trick - there should be an indicator that is not a clue for the unclued word to help determine the last letter
" Sushi loving vicar usually meets an asian from the east to surround the group and generate result"